# Social widgets with a counter (Facebook Like, Twitter Tweet, Google +1) float and width

Tags: javascript, twitter, facebook-like, google-plus

In the picture bellow I am using a container for every widget with a set width 80px, floated right and right margin 10px. However, I would like the container width to be the same as the actual width of the widget (button + the counter).

[image]

As far as I can think of it, it can't be done using CSS and unlikely using JavaScript (because of the same-origin policy). Though, is there a solution?

Comment: Have you tried without setting a size for the container elements? Please provide a test page.

Comment: Test page is http://anuary.com/. Setting no width will default to widget width.

Answer (score 1):

Even if same-origin wasn't an issue, if you managed to read the actual width from any element in the widget implementation, you couldn't rely on that, because the widget structure could change anytime, breaking your code.

So I guess as of now the answer is: no, there isn't a solution.

In the last period I always ended up showing widgets in a left aligned column, because they are really ugly aligned horizontally.

However I just found  a jQuery plugin who looks a really promising workaround: http://sharrre.com/.